# Order of declensions (склонения)

Tags: грамматика, склонение

I'm learning Russian, and I see it mentioned in study material that Russian nouns have three declensions (склонения). In English-language learning material, the order of the declensions is like so:

1. First declension: Most masculine and neuter nouns
2. Second declension: Mostly feminine nouns ending in -а or -я
3. Third declension: Mostly for feminine nouns ending in consonant + ь or ending in -мя

However, I've seen it mentioned a few times that the order of these declensions is different for Russian schools. Is there a standard order that native speakers are usually taught?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Russian (and other postsoviet) schools the classification is given as follows:

- **I склонение** (1st declension): masculine and feminine nouns ending in -а -я. This is what you refer to as Second Declension
- **II склонение** (2nd declension): most masculine nouns not ending in -a and neuter nouns ending in -о and -е. Тhis is what you refer to as First Declension
- **III склонение** (3rd declension): feminine nouns ending in ь (ь is always preceeded by a consonant)
- **Разносклоняемые существительные** (11 or so irregular nouns ending in -мя and путь)
- **Несклоняемые существительные** (undeclinable nouns): those that do not change, e.g. кенгуру.

This is by far not an ideal classification, but it's good enough and simple enough. An example of a more sophisticated classification is [the classification by Zaliznyak](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%3a%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F_%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%B0), used in [Russian Wictionary](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0)

Answer (score 6):

Shvedova in *Русская Грамматика* calls the declension of *стол* the first declension, the declension of *мама* the second declension.

Zaliznyak in *Русское именное словоизменение* does the opposite.

Traditionally, the Russian declensions corresponded to Latin ones, so the traditional way (and I believe that's what is taught in schools) would correspond to Zaliznyak's opinion: declension `I` is for nouns ending in `-a`, `-я`, declension `II` is for masculine and neuter nouns.