# Declension chart

Tags: падежи, склонение, resources

Many years ago, more than ten, I stopped studying Russian. Even quite understand things, I can read and understand (almost) without problems. However I would like to practice and improve my Russian.

However in my last move I lost some of the material I had, including a table of declensions which unfortunately I could not recover. I searched a similar online, without success so far. What I seek is to have something with which I could see at a glance the endings for each case, according to the gender and number. (I Remember that there is a paradigm for nouns and another for adjectives).

And since I found this fabulous site, I thought maybe someone might have thought of somewhere or something to help me.

In fact I don't need the table as is done, I am a typographer and I can compose my own, is enough to have declension paradigms and examples, I can do the rest and share it with you later.

Comment: Do you need something like that? [http://www.learnrussianweb.com/2010/06/blog-post_15.html](http://www.learnrussianweb.com/2010/06/blog-post_15.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I understand, you are asking about declension table for printing. Actually, there are lots of them around the Internet. For instance, on [LearnRussian.RT](http://learnrussian.rt.com/grammar-tables/declension/) (check the other tables there also). It’s quite impossible to say, which of them do you recall.

I also would suggest to use a dictionary, where you can look for declension / conjugation of any specific Russian noun, adjective / verb. That is *Грамматический словарь русского языка А. А. Зализняка* and it is also available online: [original version](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/query.cgi?root=/usr/local/share/starling/morpho&morpho=1&basename=morpho%5Czaliznia%5Cdict), [with community inprovements](http://www.morfologija.ru/).

Comment: Wow, I never found something so complete. I'll check the links, in fact it's better than I had thought.

Comment: Zalizniak's dictionary is great but it may scare the beginner leaner of Russian :-).

Comment: Have you seen this app? It's very helpful: [Grand Russian Dictionary](http://tinyurl.com/yaw79pbt) @farfareast

Answer (score 7):

I learned using charts photocopied from the back of a textbook called *Live From Moscow* (now out of print). Years later when I had to teach a class I looked online for something similar, but found nothing. So I created one in OpenOffice Writer, started a website, and put it online. Here is what it looks like:

[image: sample of case tables]

The full set is two pages long: [Russian Case Charts](https://www.readyrussian.org/Handouts/Grammar%205--Case%20Charts.html)

The Openoffice file is provided, so you can reformat the chart if you like. It distributed under a Creative Commons license.

When I was learning the cases I found the full chart too much to memorize. But once I understood the spelling rules I discovered that some of the changes were phonetic and that there were not as many different declensions as there appear to be. So, I made another set of charts to help students to see this. Here is an example from the first part:

[image: simplified noun chart]

The second part explains how hard and soft vowels work and how once we can see the declension rules as separate from the spelling rules the chart is much simpler:

[image: vowel pairs chart]

[Abbreviated Case Charts](https://www.readyrussian.org/Handouts/Grammar%206--Abbreviated%20Case%20Charts.html)

I would suggest starting with the full chart to get a feel of how declension works and use the abbreviated chart if you get stuck trying to memorize it.

Comment: I was looking for exactly something like this! A compressed table with the most fundamental rules, finally found it! Many thanks for your work

Comment: Well written post, but I did happen to notice that [**the Wikipedia page on Russian declension**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_declension) says that first declension is for (and this is almost completely straight copy from the page): feminine nouns ending with -а / -я and some masculine nouns having the same form as those of feminine gender such as "папа" or "дядя" (as well as for those words that can be masculine or feminine such as "задира."  Anybody care to comment on this?  Is the Wikipedia page incorrect?

Comment: @LisaBeck It is a case of competing terminologies. See https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/289/order-of-declensions-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: @David42  I had no idea.  With the exception of some basic introductory courses, most of my Russian language training has been of the autodidactic form, and via that method, some things get missed, so thank you for taking the time to enlighten me on this.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the declension of any noun, adjective, and the conjugation of any verb on [this](http://rifmovnik.ru) site. Just enter a word (in any form) in the top field and select словоформы from the dropdown menu that reads рифмы by default. You will see the stress indicated in red type for every single form.

Enjoy!