# Can someone help explain case declension

Tags: склонение

In my work book there are a set of rules for Nominative case ect. Now what I’m having trouble with is what the difference is between (first declension, second declension, and third declension.) In the book it say that First declension is mostly Masculine and Neuter, while the second declension is generally Feminine, and that the third declension is always Feminine. What I want to know is how to see if a word is in the first, or the second, or the third.

Comment: It's the other way around: you figure out the declension by the gender. The gender can be looked up in the dictionary. The gender and the ending define which declension should be used for a noun.

Answer (score 1):

Case declension is easier if you know the noun genders. No way around memorizing noun genders. Once you know the noun gender, everything else, relative pronouns, adjective, pronouns, prepositions, participles etc. falls into place (in time).

Answer (score -1):

Determining declension by grammatical gender is a rather strange entertainment. Declension is determined by the last letter of the word.

Examples:

*проблема* — the word has the last letter "a", which means the 2nd declension;

*мужчина* — 2nd decl.

*земля* — 2nd decl.

*армия* — we will refrain from defining it for the time being, because the words ending with -ия, -ий (санаторий, депозитарий), -ие (здание, решение) are an exception.

*Конь* and *лошадь* — here we have "ь" and so it's time to pay attention to the grammatical gender

Comment: А что уже поменяли номера склонений? Всю жизнь было: мама, дядя -- первое; стол, конь -- второе; мышь, ночь -- третье.

Comment: @C-F В большинстве англоязычных учебников русского языка склонения пронормированные как в этом ответе. 
https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/289/order-of-declensions-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Answer (score -2):

According to the suffix of a word. As you know suffixes can show you neutral,feminine or masculine the word is.[image]

Comment: Right there on this picture there are the words _папа, поляна, конь, сирень_. How can one deduce their genders from the suffixes alone?

Comment: @Quassnoi Gender is written on the picture itself. м.р. - male, ж.р - female

Answer (score -3):

First declensions consists mostly of feminine nouns as well as masculine nouns that end in a or я. Examples of these words are мама (mom), девочка (girl), папа (dad) and дядя (uncle). Second declension nouns include masculine words with zero endings and neuter words that end in e or o. Examples include cтул (chair) and зеркало (mirror).